# Dockerfile copy not working in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the EB CLI to deploy a docker image into AWS. I have a few copy commands in my Dockerfile and they do not appear to be working. This is my file structure.
[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alqutami/rtmp-hls

COPY custom.conf /usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY cogc.html /usr/local/nginx/html/players

EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "rtmp-server",
      "image": "alqutami/rtmp-hls",
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 1935,
          "containerPort": 1935
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The image deploys without error. I can view the content on the server. However, my custom conf and my custom html do not appear to have deployed.

Comment: What environment is this built in?  I would first ensure it works locally as a sanity check (build it, run it, exec into it to make sure files are indeed present).  If it works locally, I would then investigate your build time environment, if this is built in a pipeline of some sort, I would double check that all the expected files exist in the docker build context.

Comment: Sorry! The environment is "Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux". That is a good idea... I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I did a docker build and ran that build within Docker on my local machine. I was able to access my html page. I believe that everything is good with my dockerfile.

Comment: The build isn't in any pipeline. I'm doing an 'eb deploy' to update elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: It looks like the image you're naming in the EB configuration is the `FROM` base image of your custom image; do you need to change that name to match what you're building?

Comment: How do I determine the name of the build that I should be referencing? When I run locally, I provide the name.

Comment: From the elastic beanstalk docs it looks like it will behave differently depending on if you are using docker compose or a aws.json file.  Could you post the contents of docker-compose.yml and also try removing it/removing the aws.json file to see if that helps?  Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.no-compose

Comment: I deleted the docker-compose file and re-deployed. Same issue.

Comment: I found the source of my issue. According to AWS...

Building custom images during deployment with a Dockerfile is not supported by the multicontainer Docker platform on Elastic Beanstalk. Build your images and deploy them to an online repository before creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html